# Flexslider: Overall colors change

Tags: jquery, css, macos, colors, flexslider

Hey there stackoverflow,

### Edit

It seems that [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) is causing the color change. It doesn't appear when it gets excluded. Still no idea why though.

### Problem

Working on a website with my Macbook Pro - external Dell Ultrasharp is attached. I wrote a .scss file with gets compiled via Codekit. The generated .css is then uploaded.

Now I have two pages using this css file, but when I switch from one page to the other (on the Ultrasharp Monitor) the colors seem to change. They get a little bit more/less saturated it seems. I double checked the css with the Developer Tools in Chrome - no error there. Exact the same colors. The problem doesn't occur on the macbook pro - only when I select mirror displays.

I ran several color calibration tools and played with the color settings directly on the monitor - which does change the overall color - but the change on the page is still visible.

Anyone has ever experienced such a strange thing? I dont know what to do. Although this is possible only a local error for me and not very relevant to visitors of the page, I would like to get behind and fix it.

Here is a screenshot of the colors of both pages compared:

[image: Page1 and Page2]

Also when dragging the page from my macbook pro to the attached display the colors are correct for a second (or so) and then they change.

Comment: Have you checked the settings for color management?

Comment: I have the same effect when one page has a video embedded. Is any of your page showing a video or something?

Comment: What do you mean by 'checked'? I did change the color management settings and profiles - which did change the overall look of the monitor colors, but page1 and page2 still had different colors.

Comment: No video embedded - but there is a jquery slider on one. Going to exclude it and see if that helps..

Comment: Flexslider seems to be the issue - thanks for the idea! Still don't know why...

Comment: Hm... then maybe i was wrong blaming the video - there's also bootstrap carousel on that page.

Comment: really strange is that with the color picker both colors are the same... but they are clearly **not**.